# Get list of sqlite databases using Java (BlueJ)

Tags: java, database, sqlite, bluej

So I'm currently learning SQLite using Java (BlueJ) and this is my first time using SQLite, and I'm curious how to see the existing databases on my projects folder, let's say I have 3 databases in my folder, and I want to look at the names of those databases, and then take them as variables so I can switch to those databases.

I've been looking for it all the time, but only found how to do it with MySql.

Comment: I'm not much experienced with databases but I think that you may want to add a screenshot or a minimal reproducible example in order to make your question more likely to be answered.

Comment: @HoRn sorry, my bad, but honestly i can't do a screenshot or an example for the question that i have asked, because, well, i don't know how to start, but i have asked my lecturer about this issue, and yeah seems like sqlite can't do that such thing. But, maybe my lecture gone wrong!, so, yeah, maybe i will keep this question alive. Thanks for your advice!, have a nice day!